# missing token metadata

Tags: smartpy, tokens

I believe with this operation ooDavbDYs9SkBR4JoaUxTBysvEnd7y1gP1ZDGddQgfQZaURpdjx I have created a token.
This is the entry point I called

```
@sp.entry_point
    def mintDiezDAO(self, params):
        sp.verify(sp.sender == self.data.administrator)
        sp.set_type(params, sp.TList(sp.TRecord(to_=sp.TAddress, amount=sp.TNat)))
        sp.for e in params:
            user = self.ledger_key.make(e.to_, 0)
            sp.if self.data.ledger.contains(user):
                self.data.ledger[user].balance += e.amount
            sp.else:
                self.data.ledger[user] = Ledger_value.make(e.amount)
            sp.if self.data.token_metadata.contains(0):
                pass
            sp.else:
                self.data.token_metadata[0] = sp.record(
                    token_id=0,
                    token_info={"": sp.pack("ipfs://QmXvuWe3oA8vbJ2g5ERKiECfkCPgYxuC2ZyK9QomtaCiKy")}
                    )
```

But in the wallet, the icon and the unit are not displayed.
[image: token view in wallet]

Do I need to call the Token_metadata first?
But then, what do I need to pass as Handler?
[image: Handler for Token_metadata]

Any help really appreciated,

Comment: That entry_point is not in the template. (You are probably missing the token_metadata.)

Comment: thank you so much! really appreciate you help!
Using the fa2 template Mint, in smartpy explorer, I cannot find how to fill the token_info box, to have a token like this: 

{"name":"diezDAO","symbol":"diezDAO","decimals":6,"shouldPreferSymbol":false,"thumbnailUri":"ipfs://QmW6G3xK1ssrpDBNuJ17wGzcjbK6dAF9Dj4bMr87Csokd9"} 

In the "Token_info" box, I select "Four", 
then add the 4 key pairs, but I get 

Cannot convert 'diezDAO' into bytes for path mint.token_info.list.Four.0.1

Comment: You are probably putting the key in the value field. Left box is the key and the right box is the value.